# Persistance.xml vs DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets, persistence

I am using JPA 2.0, Hibernate 3 Annotation Version, the problem is that i am confusing in Persistence.xml & DispatcherServlet

My persistence.xml file contains:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="Hello" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
         <class>models.student</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

In my dispatcher servlet file I have following Beans:

```xml
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="admin" />
</bean>


<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="Hello" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>



<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

Question is: why do we need to put all properties (DriverClassName, URL, UserName, Password) in both persistence.xml and in DataSource bean in DispatcherServlet?

I am learning and it is confusing me, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have double configuration here.

You need either `persistence.xml` or bean definitions.

Take a look [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-setup)